# Strlen() and Non-Latin Characters

Tags: php, string, strlen

I have this code `case strlen($search_term) > 15:` in my `switch` statement. I cannot figure out why Greek characters are parsed different. For example a `string` in Latin with the length of 10 passes the `case` but if the `string` is in Greek, it does not.

Except the solution i would appreciate an explanation of my problem.

Comment: mb_strlen for greek characters !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strlen()` returns the **bytes** of the string, not the length.

Many greek characters are 2 bytes instead of 1, thats why you think you take wrong results.

Use `mb_strlen()` instead : http://lt.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes it makes sense now! Thank you!